# dc charts look different when building Angular App in production mode

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm currently working on an application that is using **d3, dc, and crossfilter** to render some charts.

- crossfilter2: v1.4.6
- d3: v3.5.17
- dc: v2.2.1

I was working on making the Y scale only showing inter numbers without a decimal point.

This is working when I run my application in development mode with 'ng serve'.

[image]

But when I build my app in production mode the Y scale is not the same.

[image]

Really the only thing different here is using "ng serve" or "ng build --prod".

The code that sets the ticks is

```js
  /* grpProductType is a crossfilter.Group*/
  const maxY = d3.max(d3.values(grpProductType))(1)[0]?.value;

  if (maxY < 7) {

    /* dcStepsByProductType is a dc.BarChart*/
    dcStepsByProductType.yAxis().ticks(maxY);

  }
```

I have managed to narrow down what is causing the problem to a certain point. The problem is dependant on the property the *angular.json* file under:

> projects => [app name] => architect => build => configurations => production => optimization => scripts

If this flag is true then the logic error occurs, if false then the app runs fine.

The logs when printing out when the value is true (with error) are
[image]

When the value is false (working correctly) then the logs are
[image]

It seems the return value from invoking the 'all' function is the difference.

**My question is what could be possible reasons for this?**

Comment: I guess the close vote is because you don't include enough info to debug. I understand... it's hard to make a repro... but it's also hard for people to troubleshoot this without one. Anyway, is the bad behavior consistent with the hypothesis that your `.ticks()` is not getting called? If so, I would confirm that by setting a breakpoint and seeing if it gets called in prod mode (or if it gets called in the wrong order). For example, you have written `?.`, so you expect the data not to be there sometimes... is it there in dev mode but not prod?

Comment: @Gordon After putting logs everywhere the 'ticks()' function is in fact not getting called because the max value is undefined. For some reason, the all() function returns a different value depending on the script's optimization boolean in the angular.json. I edited the original question with more details. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and your debug output specify

```
d3.values(grpProductType)
```

but it looks like `grpProductType` is a crossfilter group object, so this produces an array of the methods of the object:

[image: d3.values debug]

Then your code proceeds to compute the maximum of these *functions*, and then calls that function with a parameter `1`, takes the first element of the resulting array, and reads its field `value` if any:

```
const maxY = d3.max(d3.values(grpProductType))(1)[0]?.value;
```

I think this must be autocomplete-driven software development, because the intention is inscrutable to me. It probably works in develop mode because the maximum of the *functions* is `.top()` (by name?) but in optimized prod mode the functions have shorter nonsense names, so you call a different function.

Anyway, it's a crossfilter group object, so you should directly call [.all()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_all) to retrieve the bins. This will return an array of `{key,value}` objects, so a better way to calculate `maxY` is:

```
const maxY = d3.max(grpProductType.all(), d => d.value);
```

Or if you prefer to use `.top()`:

```
const maxY = grpProductType.top(1)[0].value;
```

Comment: Thanks, I only just got around to implementing but it works straight away :)